Next js Image component issues: lazy loading and import next/image
When I am simply importing the Image component of Next.js using:
import Image from "next/image";

it throws error Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
So I looked it up on next js issues and it was said that Image can be used like this:
import ImageModule from "next/image";
const Image = ImageModule.default;

Why is that?
Secondly, the images are not lazily loading through the Image component, even though I add the
loading="lazy"

attribute, as even though I have not scrolled to some images yet they are being fetched and loaded in the networks tab.
This is the code:
import ImageModule from "next/image";
const Image = ImageModule.default;
import Button from "../ui/Button";
import DateIcon from "../icons/date-icon";
import classes from "./EventItem.module.css";
import AddressIcon from "../icons/address-icon";
import ArrowRightIcon from "../icons/arrow-right-icon";

function EventItem(props) {
  const { title, imagePath, date, location, id } = props;

  const humanReadableDate = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    year: "numeric",
  });

  const formattedAddress = location.replace(", ", "\n");

  const exploreLink = `/events/${id}`;

  const fullImagePath = `/${imagePath}`;

  return (
    <li className={classes.item}>
      <Image
        src={fullImagePath}
        alt={title}
        width={250}
        height={160}
        loading="lazy"
      />
      <div className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.summary}>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <div className={classes.date}>
            <DateIcon />
            <time>{humanReadableDate}</time>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.address}>
            <AddressIcon />
            <address>{formattedAddress}</address>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <Button link={exploreLink}>
            <span>Explore Events</span>
            <span className={classes.icon}>
              <ArrowRightIcon />
            </span>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}

export default EventItem;


Please helpp!

You should import the Image component and not the image module
import Image from 'next/image'
 
export default function EventItem({ title, imagePath, date, location, id }) {
  return (
    <Image
       src={fullImagePath}
       alt={title}
       width={250}
       height={160}
    />
  )

The Next.js image component lazy loads images by default.

I'm sorry there was a typo actually in the question, but still with Image component being imported it is giving me errors
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
and it wouldn't render the page. But when I switch back to  it works fine

can you reproduce the issue in the code sandbox ?
